# Not able to print R tree in a output file

Tags: c++

Not able to print r tree using print function given an input.txt.
Unable to get any output.
input is- 
add 2 3 1 2 1
add 7 10 1 2 2
add 1 2 5 8 3
print

```
ifstream 
inputFile("C:/Users/YOLO/Documents/NetBeansProjects/rtree_header/input.txt"); 
  ofstream outFile; outFile.open("C:/Users/YOLO/Documents/NetBeansProjects/rtree_header/output.txt");

if (operation == "print") {
        myRtree.PrintRtree(outFile);
        continue;
    }
```

// I want to print tree structure in an output file

```
void Rtree::PrintRtree(ofstream &outputStream) {
if (outputStream.is_open() == true) {
    if (root->childs == NULL) {
        outputStream << "tree is empty" << endl;
        return;
    }
    _PrintRtree(root, 0, outputStream);
    outputStream << endl;
}
else
    cout << "output stream error" << endl;
}
```

// I want to print tree structure containg root,node and leaves

```
void Rtree::_PrintRtree(Node* curNode, int level, ofstream &outputStream) {
for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
    outputStream << "\t";
}

switch (curNode->type) {
case NODE:
    outputStream << "NODE";
    break;
case LEAF:
    outputStream << "LEAF";
    break;
case OBJECT:
    outputStream << "OBJECT";
    break;
}
outputStream << " x1=" << curNode->covering.x1
             << " x2=" << curNode->covering.x2
             << " y1=" << curNode->covering.y1
             << " y2=" << curNode->covering.y2;

if (curNode->type == OBJECT)
    outputStream << " data=" << curNode->data << endl;
else {
    outputStream << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < curNode->objCount; i++) {
        _PrintRtree(curNode->childs[i], level + 1, outputStream);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific than "not able to". Compilation problem? No output? Wrong output? If it's wrong, then in what way? Something else?

Comment: It is running without any error but no output